# Dynamically adding text boxes in html using JavaScript (syntax error occurs)

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, textbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i =1;
        function addkid(){
            if(i<=3){
                i++;
                var div=document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML="Child:<input type="text" name="child_1">
                <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />
                    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removekid(this)">";
                 document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
            }
        }
        function removekid(div){
            document.getElementById('kids'.removeChild(div.parentNode);
                                    i--;
                                    }


    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form>
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
            <div id="kids">
                Child:<input type="text" name="child_1">
                <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />(limit 3) 


            </div>
            Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />        

        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

This is my html code which has a JavaScript function to add a text box  dynamically when the '+' button is clicked, but the program does not work giving an error:

> (check5.php?name=&child_1=&phone=:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   identifier)` in the JavaScript function part 1.

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Does the error tell you which line the error occurs on? If you are looking in the browser's console it should show the line number as a link, and if you click it it should show the actual code with the problem highlighted. (And actually the colour-based syntax highlighting that Stack Overflow has applied to your code shows the problem: you haven't escaped the nested quotes in the line `div.innerHTML = ...`.)

Comment: "Child:<input type="text" name="child_1"> this line gives the error

Comment: can you please correct it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the string literal in this assignment:

```
div.innerHTML="Child:<input type="text" name="child_1">
            <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />
                <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removekid(this)">";
```

When your string is declared with `"` characters you have to use backslashes to escape any `"` characters needed in the string itself. Also, you can't have line breaks in the middle of a string literal (unless it is an ES6 string declared with back-ticks instead of quotation marks).

So try this, with escaping and no carriage returns:

```
div.innerHTML = "Child:<input type=\"text\" name=\"child_1\">"
  + " <input type=\"button\" id=\"add_kid()\" onclick=\"addkid()\" value=\"+\" />"
  + " <input type=\"button\" value=\"-\" onclick=\"removekid(this)\">";
```

Or you can surround the string with single quotes and then you don't have to escape double quotes:

```
div.innerHTML = 'Child:<input type="text" name="child_1">'
  + ' <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />'
  + ' <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removekid(this)">';
```

Either way I have removed the line breaks in the string by concatenating three string literals so that it can still be formatted as three lines in your code. You could instead just make it one long line:

```
    div.innerHTML = 'Child:<input type="text" name="child_1"> <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addkid()" value="+" /> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removekid(this)">';
```

If you need an actual newline character in your string you use `\n`, like `"This string has a newline here:\nThank you."`

**Update:** You were also missing a `)` after `'kids'` on this line:

```
document.getElementById('kids'.removeChild(div.parentNode);
```

Expand the following code snippet to see the above things fixed, and the code working:

```js
var i = 1;

function addkid() {
  if (i <= 3) {
    i++;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Child:<input type="text" name="child_1">'
      + ' <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />'
      + ' <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removekid(this)">';
    document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
  }
}

function removekid(div) {
  document.getElementById('kids').removeChild(div.parentNode);
  i--;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br/>
  <div id="kids">
    Child:
    <input type="text" name="child_1">
    <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />(limit 3)
  </div>
  Phone:
  <input type="text" name="phone">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanx though there is no errors now occurring :) when the "+" no addition of a new text box occurs :(

Comment: There was an error within `removekid()`. I've updated my answer, and included a working demo.

Comment: i corrected that no errors now but a new text box won,t get added also

Comment: I can't explain that, unless you have further error messages in the browser console (either when loading the page or when you press the add button). As you can see from the demo in my answer the code I've shown works.

Comment: Thanx alot great help :) i was stuck with this the whole day yesterday