# add/remove dynamic textboxes uniquely using javascript or appscript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, google-apps-script, textbox

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283622/dynamically-adding-text-boxes-in-html-using-javascript-syntax-error-occurs) which i have modified a bit to add unique numbers to the inputs.

```js
var i = 1;

function addkid() {
  i++;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var id = i;
  div.innerHTML = 'Child_' + id + ': <input type="text" name="child_' + id + '"/>' + ' <input type="button" id="add_kid()_' + id + '" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />' + ' <input type="button" id="rem_kid()_' + id + '" onclick="remkid(this)" value="-" />';
  document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
}

function remkid(div) {
  document.getElementById('kids').removeChild(div.parentNode);
  i--;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br/>
  <div id="kids">
    Child_1:
    <input type="text" name="child_1">
    <input type="button" id="add_kid()_1" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />
  </div>
  Phone:
  <input type="text" name="phone">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

When i view it in the browser, i can add/remove textboxes properly, but if i remove some textboxes from in-between, then the Child_id numbers repeat again, resulting in input textboxes with duplicate IDs.

1. How do i make sure there are no duplicate or missing ids?
2. How can i grab values from each of these dynamic textboxes using their IDs or name and create a JSON object dynamically on submit?
3. How can i pass on these values or the JSON object to Appscript?

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: This code should take care of giving unique ids to your textBox with out any gaps in the id number. I achieve this by using a function getID which keeps track of available ids in an array. Whenever we remove an element, the array value with that index is set to -1. We search for "-1" using indexOf and keep track of unused ID.

```js
var index = [];
// Array starts with 0 but the id start with 0 so push a dummy value
index.push(0);
// Push 1 at index 1 since one child element is already created
index.push(1)

function addkid() {
  
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var id = getID();
  // Set this attritube id so that we can access this element using Id 
  div.setAttribute("id","Div_"+id);
  
  div.innerHTML = 'Child_' + id + ': <input type="text" name="child_' + id + '"/>' + ' <input type="button" id="add_kid()_' + id + '" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />' + ' <input type="button" id="rem_kid()_' + id + '" onclick="remkid('+id+')" value="-" />';
  // inside of passing this parameter in remkid we pass id number
  document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
}
   
function remkid(id) {
// use the id arugment to get the div element using unique id set in addkid
  try{
var element = document.getElementById("Div_"+id)
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    index[id] = -1;
    //id number is = index of the array so we set to -1 to indicate its empty
    }
  catch(err){
    alert("id: Div_"+id)
    alert(err)
    
    }
}  
 function getID(){
   var emptyIndex = index.indexOf(-1);
   if (emptyIndex != -1){
     index[emptyIndex] = emptyIndex
     
     return emptyIndex
   } else {
   emptyIndex = index.length
   index.push(emptyIndex)
   return emptyIndex
     }
   }
```

```html
<form action ="Your app script link here" method="post">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br/>
  <div id="kids">
    Child_1:
    <input type="text" name="child_1">
    <input type="button" id="add_kid()_1" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />
  </div>
  Phone:
  <input type="text" name="phone">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Question 2,3: You can pass the value of the form to a app script using the form tag:

```
<form action= "app script web app link" method ="post/get">
```

Now to access the data using appscripts, we will have to make a web app and get a link to it. This will help you get started:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

You will create a appscript like this:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Your Spd ID")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var response = []
  response[0] = new Date() 
  response[1] = e.contentLength
  response[2] = JSON.stringify(e.parameters)
  sheet.appendRow(response)
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
}
```

And your sheet1 will receive a response like so:

```
2/12/2017 14:17:37  47  {"parameter":{"submit":"submit","child_1":"asd","phone":"1234","name":"jagan"},"contextPath":"","contentLength":47,"queryString":null,"parameters":{"submit":["submit"],"child_1":["asd"],"phone":["1234"],"name":["jagan"]},"postData":{"type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","length":47,"contents":"name=jagan&child_1=asd&phone=1234&submit=submit","name":"postData"}}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks @jagannathan alagurajan. One question: right now the jsondata only includes the dynamic textboxes values. can it also be made to include values from other static controls .e.g "name", "phone" or a date field?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, name and phone values will be passed to app script as long they are within the form tag ( <form> Input element within here will be posted to the URL </form>)

Comment: understood. what do i put in '<form action= "app script web app link" method ="post/get">' ? the link to the webapp that gets created, just as you showed how to create?

Comment: action = "put your app script url here",  method ="post" if you are using my example.  To get app script url, copy and past the dopost function in script.google.com and publish it.

Comment: Particularly interesting is your getID function. Could you elaborate on it (when free) to make my understanding clear?

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of monitoring `i` you can monitor name of last child added inside `div#kids` by using `document.querySelectorAll('#kids input[type=text]')[document.querySelectorAll('#kids input[type=text]').length-1].name.split("_")[1]`

this will get the name of last child and set the id of next child according to it.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/8Ljvgmac/1/

2. I have update the jsfiddle link and a function named `captureResponse` will dynamically iterate over childs added and return a JSONObject. You can call this function onsubmit of function.

3.You can hit a GET or POST request to Appscript and get the data in Appscript to process it

Answer (score 1):

If skipping id numbers is not a concern, you could just remove the `i--` from `remkid()`. That would prevent any duplicate IDs. Otherwise, you could do something like:

```js
var i = 1;
var removedkids = [];

function addkid() {
  if (removedkids.length > 0) {
    newid = removedkids.shift();
  } else {
    newid = i;
    i++;
  }
}

function removeKid(id) {
  removedkids = removedkids.push(id).sort();
}
```

Comment: If suppose i have added 30 text input boxes and then i go ahead and delete some input boxes say, 2, 5, 9, 16 in between, can i add these below and still maintain the sequence again from 31 onwards?

Comment: This code will remove the 2,5,9,16 forever, when you add a new kid the counter will start from 31.

Comment: Essentially your id numbers won't be consecutive and will have breaks in them like so 1,3,4,6,7,8,10-30

Comment: @Mohd Asim Suhail, but can i also fill in the blanks and then start from 31?

Comment: @Jagannathan Alagurajan, but can i also fill in the blanks and then start from 31?

Comment: i am also getting following error in jsfiddle when i fill in the fields and press Submit. "{"error": "Please use POST request"}"